# pgfplots not adjusting y axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using `pgfplots` to do a simple plot, but where the functional values are huge with very small differences. The problem is, that the y axis is not automatically scaling as it should to look good. The differences in the functional values are so small that the plot shows as a horizontal line. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Something},
            ylabel={Something else}
        ]
        \addplot table [x index=0, y index=1] {
            0    1.05554392382e+14
            1    1.05554398535e+14
            2    1.05554399989e+14
            3    1.05554401482e+14
            4    1.05554401823e+14
            5    1.05554401882e+14
            6    1.05554402382e+14
            7    1.05554402832e+14
            8    1.05554403724e+14
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I hope you can help!

Comment: There is no easy way to fix this. The numbers are huge but the difference is to small to draw. It's a typical floating point problem

Comment: How about manually providing a `ymin`? How about a logarhitmic plot?